# Get size of a file in Isolated Storage WP 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In a Windows Phone **8.0** application I calculate the size of a file with this following method:

```
Windows.Storage.FileProperties.BasicProperties props = await thisFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
size = props.Size;
```

I've read [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows.storage.storagefile.getbasicpropertiesasync) that this is for Windows Stors apps or WP 8.1 only, not below but it works and I am not getting any Exceptions. Why does it work if it's not supported? Are they going to reject my application submitting to Store?

If it's really not supported, what is the proper way, API to calculate the size of a file in Isolated Storage on WP 8.0?

Answer (score 1):

If it works, it might be the documentation problem and there is no reason to reject your application from the store.